# Focus causes window to move to front on virtual desktop switch

Tags: gnome, mouse, virtualdesktop

I use focus-follows-mouse (with a slight delay), such that I can focus on a window without clicking. I have it set to *not* raise the window when it is focussed; instead I need to click to raise.

After upgrading to 22.04, this behaviour works properly on a single virtual desktop, but if I switch to a different desktop, then if a window on the desktop to which I am switching happens to be under the cursor, not only will it gain focus but it will also be raised to the top. This is very annoying when the window should remain behind others.

Is this a bug, or is there some secret setting I can change to revert this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, It sounds like you are experiencing a bug with the focus-follows-mouse feature in Ubuntu 22.04. It is possible that this behavior has changed between the version of Ubuntu you were previously using and 22.04.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1969602